# Why I cannot access to TFS on the server via Remote Desktop?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm trying to access to TFS but it doesn't let me.
In my personal PC I open the Remote Desktop, then I proceed to connect to the server where is located the Team Foundation Server. Then inside the server, I go to the Google Chrome and try to sign in to TFS but it just asks me my credentials over and over again saying that I have to provide valid credentials to have access to the TFS.
This is the same if I try to log on from Visual Studio so, I don't know what is going on...

But if I try to access from my local machine, I mean, not from the server, I can properly enter with my TF credentials. Do any body knows whay is this happening?

I hope you can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Which browser you use from your machine?

Comment: From my local machine and from server via Remote Desktop I used Google Chrome.

Comment: I see. The issue is related to local authentication as it happens from both clients (Chrome and VS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answering my question.

I've found the issue.

The problem was that I tried to access specifying the tfs like this

tfs.site.com:8080/tfs/collection

but it was wrong. Been at server I just had to specify the url like this:

tfs:8080/tfs and that's it.

I can now access correctly to my tfs from server.

Again thank you everybody for our time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to disable the Loopback check (see [this page](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/05/24/sharepoint-disable-loopback-check-disableloopbackcheck-dword-in-registry/) for an example).